# Sinch Android - IO exception while subscribing for data. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change

Tags: android, ioexception, sinch

I have successfully added Sinch to my android project, calls work well on my S3 Mini, however, I have an OPPO A83 Phone (Android 7.1.1) that is unable to establish a call and accept incoming calls. I checked the logs and android studio shows me this:

```
03-15 15:50:22.748 26432-4088/ph.com.app.app I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
03-15 15:50:22.748 26432-4088/ph.com.app.app I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
03-15 15:50:23.265 26432-4088/ph.com.app.app I/System.out: Close in OkHttp
03-15 15:50:23.265 26432-4088/ph.com.app.app W/PubNubListener: Attempt 5 -> IO exception while subscribing for data. IllegalStateException rethrown as IOException due to Android API change
03-15 15:50:23.265 26432-4088/ph.com.app.app E/PubNubListener: Permanently failing subscribe after 6 attempts.

                                                                   [     03-15 15:50:23.277 26432: 4279 D/         ]
                                                                   [Posix_connect Debug]Process ph.com.app.app :80
```

Is this a compatibility issue? Thanks!

Comment: I tried it on an emulator as well (Google Nexus 5 - API 23). I am getting the same issue :(

Comment: please mail to support@sinch.com withe the version of the sdk you are using (trying to keep it to programming questions here, and not dedicated product support)

Comment: I already did @cjensen, still awaiting for their reply.

Comment: Found any solution? Facing same issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve my issue by moving my codes to a new project leaving build files in the old folder. Looks like an ordinary Clean won't do good.

Comment: I had the same warning log and the symptom was that two users call won't connect, cause their signaling wasn't established. So when I checked out my branch on another pc, it was working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Above solution does work, but simply from Android Studio menu **INVALIDATE CACHE AND RESTART** also fixed the problem for me.